# Android Broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

There are some question about Android4.2 Broadcast,

`android.intent.action.TIME_TICK`

`android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL`

This two protected broadcast are define in /frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Only find where register Receiver use `Context.registerRecriver()`,

Question:Where to send this Broadcast attached **android.intent.action.TIME_TICK**

Thanks

Comment: post code of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi @AnilMetatagg what your mean *post code of AndroidManifest.xml*?Why not send those Action with java code `sendBroadcast(Intent)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare in manifest file it wont be enough.Manifest file is like a blue print.You need to declare the broadcast receiver there and after that u need to register the broadcast receiver in your code here i am attaching sample broadcast receiver code.

```
 batteryLevelFilter= new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    this.registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                  //yourcode

            }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

And it only be sent by the system.

You have to register this intent programmatically  : Sent every minute.

like this

```
IntentFilter if = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
registerReceiver(YourReceiver, if);
```